# Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, smtpclient

trying to send email from WinForms application for domain user.  This works fine for recipients that are on the domain, but for external recipients gives the **Unable to Relay message**

```
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(mailServer);
            client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            client.Send(mail);
```

Is it possible to use the user's account to provide credentials?
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

I've also tried setting UseDefaultCredentials to true and false and setting Credentials to null

thanks
Matt

Comment: I stand corrected, doesn't work even if I do provide credentials.  So, would this be an exchange server setting?

Answer (score 0):

Is it throwing error for any external address or just for a specific one ?

For example, if it is a yahoomail address and it is incorrect, you will get this error. what is your mailserver ? I don't think your problem is because of credentials.

Comment: Hi Tanveer, the mail server is an exchange server. Tried two different external email addresses with same error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460489/mailbox-can-not-be-reached-mail-address-can-not-relay

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is a setting on exchange - You need to specify which pc's are allowed to relay via smtp.